# How to mock getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate()

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-jdbc, spring-junit

I am trying to mock a DAO implementation class that extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport

This is how my DAO interface looks like:

```
public interface TestDAO{

List<String> search();

}
```

This is how my implementation class is:

```
    public class TestDAOImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements TestDAO {

    public List<String> search(){

    return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(mySQLQuery,myMapSqlParameterSource, myRowMapper);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that write a mock test case to mock the behaviour of the call

```
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(mySQLQuery,myMapSqlParameterSource, myRowMapper)
```

So I want to implemented something like

```
when(getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(mySQLQuery,myMapSqlParameterSource, myRowMapper)).thenReturn(whatIWantToReturn);
```

I am unable to find any information on this. Can someone guide me. How to do this?

```
public class TestDAOImplTestCase{

    @Test
    public void testSearch(){
        when(getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(mySQLQuery,myMapSqlParameterSource, myRowMapper)).thenReturn(whatIWantToReturn); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What I want to do is return some test results when the query method is called?

Answer (score 0):

trust me, you don't want to do it. what you really want to do is do two tests:

1. the easier one: mock the whole `TestDao` interface and **unit test** if rest of your code passes correct parameters to `search` and properly handles the result
2. a bit harder one: **integration test**. take real implementation of `TestDAOImpl`, connect it to real database, prefill database with data, execute the `search` method and check if it returns correct answer